# Dialog content style

Tags: android, dialog, styles

I have SingleChoiceItems Dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
builder.setTitle("Выберите статус:")
        .setSingleChoiceItems(mStatusesAdapter, 0, null)
        .setPositiveButton("Подтвердить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
builder.show();
```

In this dialog I use my style, where I can manage title, actions, etc.

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
</style>
```

But I can't manage my content in dialog. How can I change content size?

Thanks.

### UPDATE

I explain my question.

```
.setSingleChoiceItems(mStatusesAdapter, 0, null)
```

Adapter code:

```
private ArrayList<Status> mStatuses;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mStatusesAdapter;

private class LoadInfoModel{
public ArrayList<Status> statuses;
}

loadInfoModel.statuses = DataGetHelpers.GetStatuses();

mStatuses = loadInfoModel.statuses;
    ArrayList<String> statusesTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mStatuses.size(); i++){
    statusesTitles.add(mStatuses.get(i).StatusTitle);
    }
    mListViewStatuses = new ListView(getActivity());
    mStatusesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, statusesTitles);
    mListViewStatuses.setAdapter(mStatusesAdapter);
```

I bring an adapter to display the contents of my dialog, and result:
[image]

This items have big size for me, how can I change their size?

### Answer

Just need use custom layout for your adapter where set text size.

Comment: inside <style> tag use this . **<item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>**

Comment: I tryed do it, but this chang only text size in actions buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can Customise text completely, 
Try Below code-

```
TextView title =  new TextView(context);
        title.setText("ALERT TITLE");
        title.setTextSize(50);
        title.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    builder.setCustomTitle(title);
```

Will work for You :)

Comment: This will work with titles. I can do it in my styles.
But my problem is that I can't change size items from my adapter.

Comment: adapter? you didn't mention anywhere about any adapter.
can you please elaborate what you exactly want to do ?

Comment: please post the adapter content code or please modify the radio buttons width and heights..i think your problem is to change the size of texts in RB.actually you can not do it bcz i.e the size  is built in functionality of RB so try to change The W and H of RB.

Comment: I'm deside my problem, I use my custom layout for adapter :) Thank you pushed in the right direction ;)

Answer (score 0):

try like this to change the title content...

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hello world").show();
TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
textView.setTextSize(40);
```

Comment: This will work with titles. I can do it in my styles. But my problem is that I can't change size items from my adapter

Comment: but you did not mentioned about adapter?please edit the question with full and required information to answer your question.